# Procedure to copy data from one table to another in number of batches(input parameter)

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a procedure to copy data from old table to new table in batches in SQL Server.
The input parameter for procedure is batch size (integer).

Example: If old table has 100 rows, I want to copy data into 4 batches (4*25=100)
How can I achieve that?

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE data_tran
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * INTO new_table FROM  old_table
DROP TABLE old_table
END
```

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem to me. https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Despite what you might think, SO is not a free code-writing service. At a minimum, you could at least add your parameter. A little searching will find discussions about batching large (note - emphasis on **large**) DML operations. Typically one does not "copy" rows and then immediately drop the source table. This does seem to be more than a bit of a XY problem.